# Violin Sheet music - Finger 0 on non-open string note

Tags: sheet-music, fingering, violin

I'm battling to understand the indicated fingering on one of the pieces of music I have for my Violin Grade 6 exam. As indicated below, the finger notation suggests that I need to play an open string for D which is found on the A string. This is obviously not possible. Can anybody tell me if this 0 has another meaning?

[image: score music indicating open string on d]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually, the `0` on  non-open string note indicates that this note should be played using ***[flageolet](http://www.traditionalmusic.co.uk/violin-playing/violin-playing%20-%200164.htm)***. In your example, there are three occurences of *flageolet*: the `d''` in the first bar and the `a''` and the last `d''` in the second. This is quite natural if you play this in the third position: with *flageolet*, you don't have to switch to the a string (or e string, in the second bar). Instead, the left hand remains in third position, only the Little finger (fourth finger) is placed on a different position than usual. This takes less time than switching both left hand and bow to the `a` (or `e`) string

In music notation, usually a small circle is used to notate a *flageolet*. But sometimes, instead of a circle, the `0` number is used.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this will be a harmonic. Probably the octave harmonic at the half way point of the D string. This does suggest, though, that the preceding notes are played on the D string, higher up the neck.

Comment: Yes, an when it happens later on the A above the staff, you play the harmonic in the same place but on the A-string instead of the D. The pitch will sound the same, but the timbre will be a bit purer when played as a harmonic.

Answer (score 1):

How do you know it should be played in the A string? To me it looks clear/logical to play that first bar in the third position (D string) and stretch 4th finger to the harmonic/flageolet.

In the second bar is more clear which position should be played. The 3-3 fingering in the second beat makes a inevitable glissando and the A (highest note) should be played in A string. With those fingers it will be a glissando from 1st position 4th finger/E to the flageolet (quite common). When the flageolet is "ringing" you can get the 4th finger ready for the G in the 3rd position to make that scale down to B and all that last passage in 3rd position reaching flageolet (D note) in D string.

Keep in mind all people all different. All have different sizes in hands and all have their own expression which might lead sometimes to different fingerings than suggested by a paper.